# python recursion (fractal) with irrational value output<=>input, based on fibonacci / phi basis

Tags: python, iteration, fibonacci, fractals

I am new to programming and can't figure out how to see this code to fruition, with out having to manually program the iteration in.  I know it should/can call on itself to continue the algorithm, I just cant figure out how.  A large problem is for every increase in "n" (when n<2) the output will increase from the previous, so how do I set up a recursion so that the return will result in an ever increasing 'tuple'.

I apologise in advance, i am not very articulate with what i am trying to do, but can provide any details, and I am just starting to crawl when it comes to computer programing.

Here's the code, and I'll send an image it generates on request (i tried to post it but I don't have enough 'street cred'...
(I call this first program x_sub_i)

```
from graphics import *
def fib(n):
  if n==0:
    return 0
  elif n==1:
    return 1
  else:
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)

def f(n,k):
  x = k/2*((-1)**(n+1)*fib(n)*5**.5+(-1)**n*(fib(n+1)+fib(n-1)))
  return x

  def p(n,k):
   for i in range(1,n+1):
    pt = Point(i, f(i,k))
    pt.draw(win)
    print (f(i,k))   

from x_sub_i import *

def a(n,k):
  win = GraphWin('Fractal', 800, 600)
  win.setCoords(0.0,n,k,0.0)
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    x1 = f(i,k)
    pt = Point(x1,i)
    pt.draw(win)
    line1 = Line(pt,Point(f((i+1),k), i+1))
    line1.draw(win)
    print(x1)
    for j in range(1,i-1):
        x2 =f(j,k)
        x2 = x1 + x2
        pr = Point(x2,i)
        pr.draw(win)
        line2 = Line(pr,Point(f(j,k)+f(i+1,k), i+1))
        line2.setFill('black')
        line2.draw(win)
        print(x2)
        for h in range(1,j-1):
            x3 = f(h,k)
            x3 = x3 + x2
            ps = Point(x3,i)
            ps.draw(win)
            line3 = Line(ps,Point(f(h,k)+f(j,k)+f(i+1,k), i+1))
            line3.setFill('purple')
            line3.draw(win)
            print(x3)
            for m in range(1,h-1):
                x4 = f(m,k)
                x4 = x4 + x3
                pq = Point(x4,i)
                pq.draw(win)
                line4 = Line(pq,Point(f((m),k)+f(h,k)+f(j,k)+f(i+1,k), i+1))
                line4.setFill('blue')
                line4.draw(win)
                print(x4)
                for q in range(1,m-1):
                    x5 = f(q,k)
                    x5 = x5 + x4
                    pu = Point(x5,i)
                    pu.draw(win)
                    line5 = Line(pu,Point(f((q),k)+f(m,k)+f(h,k)+f(j,k)+f(i+1,k), i+1))
                    line5.setFill('red')
                    line5.draw(win)
                    print(x5)
                    for a in range(1,q-1):
                        x6 =f(a,k)
                        x6 = x5 + x6
                        pa = Point(x6,i)
                        pa.draw(win)
                        line6 = Line(pa,Point(f((q),k)+f(m,k)+f(h,k)+f(j,k)+f(a,k)+f(i+1,k), i+1))
                        line6.setFill('orange')
                        line6.draw(win)
                        print(x6)
                        for b in range(1,a-1):
                            x7 = f(b,k)
                            x7 = x7 + x6
                            pb = Point(x7,i)
                            pb.draw(win)
                            line7 = Line(pb,Point(f((q),k)+f(m,k)+f(h,k)+f(j,k)+f(a,k)+f(b,k)+f(i+1,k), i+1))
                            line7.setFill('green')
                            line7.draw(win)
                            print(x7)
                            for c in range(1,b-1):
                                x8 = f(c,k)
                                x8 = x8 + x7
                                pc = Point(x8,i)
                                pc.draw(win)
                                line8 = Line(pc,Point(f((q),k)+f(m,k)+f(h,k)+f(j,k)+f(a,k)+f(b,k)+f(c,k)+f(i+1,k), i+1))
                                line8.setFill('pink')
                                line8.draw(win)
                                print(x8)
                                for d in range(1,c-1):
                                    x9 = f(d,k)
                                    x9 = x9 + x8
                                    pd = Point(x9,i)
                                    pd.draw(win)
                                    line9 = Line(pd,Point(f((q),k)+f(m,k)+f(h,k)+f(j,k)+f(a,k)+f(b,k)+f(c,k)+f(d,k)+f(i+1,k), i+1))
                                    line9.setFill('grey')
                                    line9.draw(win)
                                    print(x9)
```

Here's the image it generates with different colors.  If you run the code above and change the assigned colors in the code you should find a similar result.

![fractal][1]

Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated! I can provide any and all the info I have on the mathematical side of the algorithm, it's kind of been my pet project for some time now and I'd just like to see it run... efficiently and on it's own.

Thanks;)

Comment: Since you can't include the image in your post, can you edit your post to include a link to the image? I'd also like to know a little more about the algorithm from a high-level perspective. It's hard to tell what the code is supposed to do just by looking at it. Does this fractal have a name or well-known algorithm you can link us to?

Comment: Using one-letter variable names is not a good idea since it makes it very difficult to tell what the code is supposed to be doing -- for you as well as other people.  If you set this aside and come back to it in a month, you'll have no idea what you were trying to accomplish.    Anyway, it seems like a recursive function is needed here.

Comment: The `graphics` module...  can you give a reference for the `graphics` module that you're using?

Comment: ... also the `x_sub_i` module is nowhere to be found, I surrender: good luck with your question

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the first two segments of code is the x_sub_i, as seen below.

Comment: from graphics import *
def fib(n):
  if n==0:
    return 0
  elif n==1:
    return 1
  else:
    return fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)

def f(n,k):
  x = k/2*((-1)**(n+1)*fib(n)*5**.5+(-1)**n*(fib(n+1)+fib(n-1)))
  return x

  def p(n,k):
   for i in range(1,n+1):
    pt = Point(i, f(i,k))
    pt.draw(win)
    print (f(i,k))'

Comment: @Galen Harrison here is a link to the graphics module mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py, also the icon image by my username is the image that is generated.  There isn't any generalized information published about this algorithm. In general, it takes any prescribed length (k), with a set number of iterations (n) and breaks down (k) into a series of subset called (x), this is done using a pattern derived from the golden ratio.  It is, to a degree, a spin off of the cantor set using the golden ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're looking for a way to make your 'fractal generation' loop recursive. The first loop looks like some of the parameters are slightly different than the rest; I left that one alone, and generalized the rest into a helper function. Try something like this:

```
def a(n,k):
  win = GraphWin('Fractal', 800, 600)
  win.setCoords(0.0,n,k,0.0)
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    x1 = f(i,k)
    pt = Point(x1,i)
    pt.draw(win)
    line1 = Line(pt,Point(f((i+1),k), i+1))
    line1.draw(win)
    print(x1)
    loop(i, k, x1, f(i+1, k), win, 0)

COLORS = ['black', 'blue', 'red', 'orange', 'purple', 'pink', 'grey']
def loop(i, k, x1, f1, win, count):
    if count>6: # termination condition
        return
    for j in range(1,i-1):
        fjk = f(j,k)
        x2 = fjk + x1
        pr = Point(x2,i)
        pr.draw(win)
        f2 = fjk + f1
        line2 = Line(pr, Point(f2), i+1))
        line2.setFill(COLORS[count])
        line2.draw(win)
        print(x2)
        loop(j, k, x2, f2, win, count+1)
```